# Bike pedal not working

Tags: pedals

My kid got new bike but the pedal not working, it was working for two days and then stopped working I've tried to loosen it but I couldn't. Don't know what to do.

Comment: A little vague - Does the pedal not spin on its own axle, or does pushing down on the pedal not push the bike forward ?  Is it one pedal or both?   Does it not turn at all or does it sound really gritty and grinding?   Consider adding one or two photos to your question.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Sara. I see that you haven't been back since you asked this; without an update this post will be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You say its a new bike - if new from shop and its only a couple of days old, then it should be under warranty.

Consider taking the bike back for a warranty repair rather than trying to fix it yourself.